# Fixed cost associated to SlackVar(waiting time cost) [CVRPTW]

Tags: constraint-programming, or-tools, vehicle-routing, java

I'm modeling a CVRPTW with some features:

- Each type of vehicle has a cost per km and a fixed cost per trip. To calculate these costs, I am using these methods for this:
  `setSpanCostCoefficientForVehicle` and `setFixedCostOfVehicle`.
- Each customer has a time window where they can be visited. I'm using this method for this:
  `solver.addConstraint(solver.makeNotMemberCt(transitTimeDimensionCumulVar, forbiddenWindow.starts, forbiddenWindow.ends)`

So far, everything is working correctly but now, a requirement has arisen to add an extra fixed cost if a vehicle has been idle(slacking) for more than 4 hours at a customer. A vehicle can wait for the opening time of the next customer before leaving.

I'm in doubt about how I can add a fixed cost for SlackVar on each node or something like `setSlackVarSoftUpperBound`.
Is it possible to add a fixed cost associated with each customer's SlackVar? This cost does not apply to waiting at the depot.

I'm using ORTools 7.6 with Java

Comment: Posted on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/or-tools-discuss/Aw77m9Gf6b8) too.